# How to include additional files to the One Click publish process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oneclick

My C# project uses some additional text files. How can I add them to the One Click publishing process?

As far as I can see, only referenced libraries (DLL's) will be added. I can modify those files under Properits -> Publish -> Application Files. But in this menu, I can not add additional files, which are not referenced libraries.

**EDIT:** As suggested from an (already deleted) answer, I can not add the text file as a reference like a regular DLL. Visual Studio does not allow this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a folder  e.g. "textfiles"

Add all files to that folder using Add as link in the dialog box after selecting Add existing item on the folder

Mark all files as Copy if newer

Set build action to content